# Aumentar limite eixo y usando scale_y_break

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico

Olá! Estou terminando meu gráfico de colunas agrupadas usando a função scale_y_break para dar destaque às menores concentrações.

```
gr1 <- 'Lat Cr  Cu  Mn  Ni  Pb  Ti  V   Zn
15  2,85    0,00    1,25    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    32,20
14  19,51   5,16    14,60   4,32    0,00    116,33  57,69   29,96
13  10,59   2,51    6,87    3,48    3,96    3,01    28,71   7,30
12  8,23    1,87    6,92    2,52    2,82    0,00    20,06   62,36
11  9,66    2,05    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    11,72
10  8,46    5,26    2,79    1,89    2,86    0,00    16,45   18,39
9   2,78    0,00    0,94    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    28,23
8   8,85    2,37    7,07    0,64    0,00    21,07   17,20   15,33
7   9,31    3,68    5,70    3,48    4,22    3,42    35,70   104,04
6   13,42   3,64    9,19    2,95    0,00    67,49   35,26   15,35
5   2,23    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    17,93
4   3,48    0,00    0,70    0,78    2,82    0,00    5,22    8,39
3   2,92    0,00    0,24    0,00    2,90    0,00    1,05    20,36
2   2,67    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    10,96
1   2,94    0,00    0,61    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    14,21
0   6,72    1,32    2,69    2,35    2,95    0,00    19,44   11,52
-1  8,53    2,50    53,70   2,80    2,85    0,00    29,81   12,66
'

gr1 <- read.table(text = gr1, header = TRUE,
                    dec = ",", colClasses = "numeric")

gr1 %>%
  pivot_longer(-Lat, names_to = "Metals") %>%
  mutate(Lat = factor(Lat)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Lat, value, fill = Metals)) +
  scale_y_break(c(5,5.01), scales =3, expand = c(0,0))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"), width = .7)+
  xlab('Latitude')+
  ylab(expression(Concentration~nmol~L^{-1}))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Cr = '#136066', Cu = '#db4b23',Mn = '#382960', 
                               Ni = '#a30006', Pb = '#e89d10',Ti = '#770443', 
                               V = '#e0be7e', Zn = '#83870e'), name='') +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "top", axis.title = (element_text(size = 14)))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 7, col = 'grey0', linetype = 2)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 12, col = 'grey0',linetype = 2)
```

Acontece que o limite máximo do meu y não aparece mais (120) e preciso que apareça.

Quando tento o scale_y_continuous, o eixo y duplica e os intervalos aparecem nas duas verticais do gráfico.

Alguém para me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O argumento "expand" das funções `scales_...` são funções lineares que expandem os limites e precisam ser especificados juntos da função `expansion`. O primeiro argumento define a expansão de forma multiplicativa do eixo, o primeiro elemento do vetor define o limite inferior e o segundo define o limite superior:

```
gr1 %>%
  pivot_longer(-Lat, names_to = "Metals") %>%
  mutate(Lat = factor(Lat)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Lat, value, fill = Metals)) +
  scale_y_break(c(5,5.01), scales =3, expand = expansion(c(0,0.5)))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"), width = .7)+
  xlab('Latitude')+
  ylab(expression(Concentration~nmol~L^{-1}))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Cr = '#136066', Cu = '#db4b23',Mn = '#382960', 
                               Ni = '#a30006', Pb = '#e89d10',Ti = '#770443', 
                               V = '#e0be7e', Zn = '#83870e'), name='') +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "top", axis.title = (element_text(size = 14)))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 7, col = 'grey0', linetype = 2)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 12, col = 'grey0',linetype = 2)
```

Comment: Obrigada, ficou perfeito! :D